# Stationarity independent variables in GARCH

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stationarity, garch

I was wondering if included *independent* variables in a GARCH model (either in the mean- or conditional variance) need to be stationary. For example, I have interest rate data, which in itself is not stationary. Yet the first difference is stationary. Is it necessary to opt for the first difference data?

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic theory for the GARCH-X model has been developed in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.897954?journalCode=ubes20). They show that normal inference is valid even in the case where the covariates are fractionally integrated. See also the references in this paper.

I would try both strategies - both level and first difference. Another point is that I have a hard time believing that interest rates are I(1).